# Is there a difference between a TV and a TV set?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, word-usage

Why can a one-piece TV be called a "TV set" if a TV is a single item?

Comment: Tradition. From when a radio set was amps and speakers and stuff. No other reason. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_set

Comment: I rarely hear "TV set" nowadays, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=television%2Ctelly%2CTV+set%2CTV%2C&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctelevision%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctelly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTV%20set%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTV%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Today you need to talk about [plasma TVs](http://www.cnet.com/topics/tvs/best-tvs/plasma/), or flat screen/panel TVs

Comment: I think the use of *set* is a pragmatic use. It depends on using specific verb and the context.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't say "I was watching a TV set show last night."  But, except where disambiguation is necessary, "TV" can be used pretty much anywhere that "TV set" might be used, and "TV set" is becoming quite rare.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Nor would you be likely to say "I was watching a TV last night." The "a" in the expression "watching a TV show" links to "show"—not to "TV" in the sense of "idiot box." In fact, we say "I was watching TV" or "I was watching television" (with no indefinite article) to indicate that we were exposing ourselves to the medium of television—the flow of soundwaves and excited electrons or diodes or whatever. The "TV" in your example uses "TV" in that sense, I think. Unfortunately, the OP doesn't ask about the difference between "a TV" and "TV" (not to speak of "the TV").

Answer (score 5):

A TV is actually composed of many components with specific functions:  a radio receiver, a tuning control, a pre-amplifier, an amplifier, a video processing unit, a display screen.  In the early days of TV, before the advent of *semiconductors(transistors) and  integrated circuits*, these components were built with *tubes*, and each component was large enough to actually be worked on or replaced. Also, for 50 years or more, TV displays were cathode ray tubes (CRTs) called the *picture tube*; these could also be replaced separately. So the term "TV set" refers to all those components, housed in a single cabinet. Modern TVs have all these components, but in miniaturized digital electronics. The term "TV set" is becoming less common, and will probably become even less so over time.

If you go far enough back in time, you might find instances of a radio being called a *radio set*.

Comment: And today we have home theatres and surround systems, that may also be considered as a part of a "set".

Answer (score 1):

[Set](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Set) refers to:

> - A group of things of the same kind that belong together and are so used: a chess set.

so by *TV set* you mean all the main parts of it that make it a single product.

[TV Set](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tv+set) :

> - an electronic device that receives television signals and displays them on a screen; "the British call a tv set a telly"

Comment: But is it justified to call something a set if there's only one part to it? Or does the remote count to make it a set?

Comment: It is generally part of the set. Tech evolution is actually changing quickly all this. You can operate your devices with your smartphone now.

Answer (score 1):

Televisions were generally single-piece units right from the start (except for some fancy console models and the short-lived two-piece Philco setup). But "TV set" was probably the norm until maybe 1960 or 1965, when "set" was dropped.

The reason for this is probably that I lied above -- it wasn't called a "TV set" but rather a "television set" -- the word "television", by itself, referred to the medium, not the box, so "television set" was used to refer to the box.  And, obviously, "television set" was then shortened to "TV set".

Answer (score -1):

TVs used to be a "set" of components...mostly tubes. When our Magnavox console set went on the fritz, my Dad would open the back and pop out any tubes that looked burned out. My Mom and I would go to the hardware store the next day, test the tube(s) on the HW store's Tube Tester, then buy a replacement for whichever tube failed the test. By that evening, the TV set was back in operation!

Comment: In so far as this is an answer to the question, it is the same one as has already been posted by Mr. Hitchcock, years ago. Please note that the  distinction between answers and comments is essential to the Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

A TV set (or radio set) refers to a set of crystals, each cut to oscillate at a particular frequency. These were the primary component that tuned to different channels allowing reception of different signals (channels). These crystals were eventually replaced by tuned circuits and further evolved with semiconductors. The term "set" stuck and just didn't evolve with the technology.

Answer (score -2):

"TV" and "TV set" share the same meaning. They both refer to a television.

Comment: That was not the question.